# Analyzing seasonality of Google trend time series using FFT

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I am trying to evaluate the amplitude spectrum of the Google trends time series using a fast Fourier transformation. If you look at the data for 'diet' in the data provided [here](https://github.com/datacamp/datacamp_facebook_live_ny_resolution/tree/master/data) it shows a very strong seasonal pattern:

[image: Original time series, zero mean and applied Hamming window]

I thought I could analyze this pattern using a FFT, which presumably should have a strong peak for a period of 1 year.

However when I apply a FFT like this (`a_gtrend_ham` being the time series multiplied with a Hamming window):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import fft, fftshift
import pandas as pd

gtrend = pd.read_csv('multiTimeline.csv',index_col=0)

gtrend.index = pd.to_datetime(gtrend.index, format='%Y-%m')

# Sampling rate
fs = 12 #Points per year

a_gtrend_orig = gtrend['diet: (Worldwide)']
N_gtrend_orig = len(a_gtrend_orig)
length_gtrend_orig = N_gtrend_orig / fs
t_gtrend_orig = np.linspace(0, length_gtrend_orig, num = N_gtrend_orig, endpoint = False)

a_gtrend_sel = a_gtrend_orig.loc['2005-01-01 00:00:00':'2017-12-01 00:00:00']
N_gtrend = len(a_gtrend_sel)
length_gtrend = N_gtrend / fs
t_gtrend = np.linspace(0, length_gtrend, num = N_gtrend, endpoint = False)

a_gtrend_zero_mean = a_gtrend_sel - np.mean(a_gtrend_sel)
ham = np.hamming(len(a_gtrend_zero_mean))
a_gtrend_ham = a_gtrend_zero_mean * ham

N_gtrend = len(a_gtrend_ham)
ampl_gtrend = 1/N_gtrend * abs(fft(a_gtrend_ham))
mag_gtrend = fftshift(ampl_gtrend)
freq_gtrend = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, len(ampl_gtrend))
response_gtrend = 20 * np.log10(mag_gtrend)
response_gtrend = np.clip(response_gtrend, -100, 100)
```

My resulting amplitude spectrum does not show any dominant peak:

[image: Amplitude spectrum of time series]

Where is my misunderstanding of how to use the FFT to get the spectrum of the data series?

Comment: Could you please include the code lines where you read the data and apply the hamming window?   I am pretty sure that I can answer this for you.  A complete (but minimal) code example will save me some time.

Comment: Hi @DrM, thanks for your comment. I added the missing lines.

Comment: ok, got it.   Is your gtrend.csv simply a copy of the multiTimeline.csv from the web site?  Also, presumably you have some import statements for pandas and numpy.  Assuming the data file works out-of-the-box, I'll try to get back to you shortly.

Comment: Yes gtrend.csv is simply a copy of multiTimeline.csv. I will add the import statements in a second.

Comment: you also need a skiprows=2, I get a runtime error divide by zero at log10 after the shift.  But that's probably okay, as a starting point. I have to put something away and will look at this in a few minutes.  It should not take long to sort it out.

Comment: Okay, here is the answer.   I hope this is helpful.  If so, please dont forget to mark it correct and/or give it an up-vote.

Comment: Okay, that's it, done editing.   Notice the spectra at the bottom, they look pretty good to me.

Comment: I found the origin of the high frequency components, check it out.  Its the fast rise and fall of the spikes in the raw data.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is a clean implementation of what I think you are trying to accomplish. I include graphical output and a brief discussion of what it likely means.

First, we use the rfft() because the data is real valued.  This saves time and effort (and reduces the bug rate) that otherwise follows from generating the redundant negative frequencies.   And we use rfftfreq() to generate the frequency list (again, it is unnecessary to hand code it, and using the api reduces the bug rate).

For your data, the Tukey window is more appropriate than the Hamming and similar cos or sin based window functions.  Notice also that we subtract the median before multiplying by the window function.  The median() is a fairly robust estimate of the baseline, certainly more so than the mean().

In the graph you can see that the data falls quickly from its intitial value and then ends low. The Hamming and similar windows, sample the middle too narrowly for this and needlessly attenuate a lot of useful data.

For the FT graphs, we skip the zero frequency bin (the first point) since this only contains the baseline and omitting it provides a more convenient scaling for the y-axes.

You will notice some high frequency components in the graph of the FT output.
I include a sample code below that illustrates a possible origin of those high frequency components.

Okay here is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import rfft, rfftfreq
from scipy.signal import tukey

from numpy.fft import fft, fftshift
import pandas as pd

gtrend = pd.read_csv('multiTimeline.csv',index_col=0,skiprows=2)
#print(gtrend)

gtrend.index = pd.to_datetime(gtrend.index, format='%Y-%m')
#print(gtrend.index)

a_gtrend_orig = gtrend['diet: (Worldwide)']
t_gtrend_orig = np.linspace( 0, len(a_gtrend_orig)/12, len(a_gtrend_orig), endpoint=False )

a_gtrend_windowed = (a_gtrend_orig-np.median( a_gtrend_orig ))*tukey( len(a_gtrend_orig) )

plt.subplot( 2, 1, 1 )
plt.plot( t_gtrend_orig, a_gtrend_orig, label='raw data'  )
plt.plot( t_gtrend_orig, a_gtrend_windowed, label='windowed data' )
plt.xlabel( 'years' )
plt.legend()

a_gtrend_psd = abs(rfft( a_gtrend_orig ))
a_gtrend_psdtukey = abs(rfft( a_gtrend_windowed ) )

# Notice that we assert the delta-time here,
# It would be better to get it from the data.
a_gtrend_freqs = rfftfreq( len(a_gtrend_orig), d = 1./12. )

# For the PSD graph, we skip the first two points, this brings us more into a useful scale
# those points represent the baseline (or mean), and are usually not relevant to the analysis
plt.subplot( 2, 1, 2 )
plt.plot( a_gtrend_freqs[1:], a_gtrend_psd[1:], label='psd raw data' )
plt.plot( a_gtrend_freqs[1:], a_gtrend_psdtukey[1:], label='windowed psd' )
plt.xlabel( 'frequency ($yr^{-1}$)' )
plt.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

And here is the output displayed graphically.  There are strong signals at 1/year and at 0.14 (which happens to be 1/2 of 1/14 yrs), and there is a set of higher frequency signals that at first perusal might seem quite mysterious.

We see that the windowing function is actually quite effective in bringing the data to baseline and you see that the relative signal strengths in the FT are not altered very much by applying the window function.

If you look at the data closely, there seems to be some repeated variations within the year.  If those occur with some regularity, they can be expected to appear as signals in the FT, and indeed the presence or absence of signals in the FT is often used to distinguish between signal and noise.   But as will be shown, there is a better explanation for the high frequency signals.

[image: Raw and windowed signals, and amplitude spectra]

Okay, now here is a sample code that illustrates one way those high frequency components can be produced.   In this code, we create a single tone, and then we create a set of spikes at the same frequency as the tone.  Then we Fourier transform the two signals and finally, graph the raw and FT data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import rfft, rfftfreq

t = np.linspace( 0, 1, 1000. )

y = np.cos( 50*3.14*t )

y2 = [ 1. if 1.-v < 0.01 else 0. for v in y ]

plt.subplot( 2, 1, 1 )
plt.plot( t, y, label='tone' )
plt.plot( t, y2, label='spikes' )
plt.xlabel('time')

plt.subplot( 2, 1, 2 )
plt.plot( rfftfreq(len(y),d=1/100.), abs( rfft(y) ), label='tone' )
plt.plot( rfftfreq(len(y2),d=1/100.), abs( rfft(y2) ), label='spikes' )
plt.xlabel('frequency')
plt.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Okay, here are the graphs of the tone, and the spikes, and then their Fourier transforms.  Notice that the spikes produce high frequency components that are very similar to those in our data.
[image]

In other words, the origin of the high frequency components is very likely in the short time scales associated with the spikey character of signals in the raw data.

Comment: Wow, that's amazing and also explained very insightful. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I see you are working on fluid flows.  In physical measurements a spectrum like this might result from harmonics in the underlying physical phenomenon or can arise in the electronics of the measurement  system.

Comment: Yes I mainly work on fluids at the workplace. However this time I asked more out of interest. That's why I also used the Google trends input. And I actually learned a lot!

Comment: Check out the book Digital Filters by Hamming, its available as a Dover book.  If you can pick up the ideas and generalize, then that can be a good entry to the topic.

Comment: The fact that this reply only has 5 upvotes is practically criminal.

Comment: how come that all threads that are discussing fft never label their y-axis? What is the unit in this case? And more general: if you apply an fft to a dataset, are the output values the coefficients of the FT? Thank you very much

Comment: If you read the code, you can see that the y axis in this case is amplitude.   Properly, for a power spectrum density, the quantity should be power, i.e., the square amplitude. The raw output of an FFT is the complex amplitude  for each frequency bin, so yes, it is effectively the coefficients of the FT.  However, be aware that there are different normalization schemes for FFTs, so you might want to check how this is handled in the FFT implementation that you are using.

Comment: @DrM how can we get the delta-time from the data using numpy/scipy or similar utilities?

Comment: @TPPZ   I am happy to answer you question.  By delta-time,  do you mean the the sampling interval, or the interval between two events?

Comment: @DrM I mean the `d` parameter of `rfftfreq`. I think that from the FFT pov that's the sampling interval, however I guess the rate at which the events are provided in the time series matters as well. There's some rust in my FFT knowledge (I am trying to fill the knowledge gaps), so I am confusing as well the big omega with the frequency when comparing spikes in the spectrogram, it might be related to that `d` parameter. Thanks!

Comment: @TPPZ   It's the sample spacing (see the rfftfreq documentation at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html).    Generally, the sample spacing is an input or control parameter when the data was generated (or retrieved).   The alternative, where the data is event driven with non constant sample intervals, can be Fourier transformed as a sum.   The fast Fourier transform (FFT) assumes a constant sampling interval.