# Difference between scipy periodogram and self implemented power spectral density

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to evaluate the frequency domain of several signals. For this I used the PSD implementation given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52691914/3562088). As a comparison I used the `signal.periodogram` function provided in scipy:

```
from scipy.signal import tukey
import scipy as sp
f, Pxx_den = sp.signal.periodogram(a_gtrend_orig,12,window=tukey( len(a_gtrend_orig) ))
```

However when I plot this next to the self-implemented PSD they look significantly different:

[image: Comparison of PSD algorithms]

As the same window function is used and the periodogram function should also use an FFT where does this difference coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example that you are comparing this to, is graphing the **amplitude** at each frequency bin, i.e, abs(fft())

The periodogram produces a **power** spectral density, that means it is the **square of the amplitude** at each frequency bin.

The label "windowed psd" is from an early edit, and was corrected later.

Comment: Ah that makes sense!

Comment: great, you can mark the answer as correct also, if you like.