# How can I apply fourrier transform to my dataset using python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, signal-processing

I'm new to signal processing. I have a dataset comprised of vibrational data I collected using an accelerometer as can be seen in this picture

[image]

I have been trying to apply fourrier transform to this dataset to determine the dominant frequencies and get a plot like this one

[image]

Comment: You can use Numpy https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html#numpy.fft.fft  Example with plot: https://plot.ly/matplotlib/fft/

Comment: Welcome @MOHAMED KOUBAA! Please provide in your question what you have tried so far and why the results are not at expected.

Comment: Hello , Thank you
Actually , all the exemples provided , including this one , are applied on sine waves , I want to apply it to the dataset shown in the image i attached

Comment: Which column of your dataset?

Comment: Could please post your data set online, and provide a link to it?    In your question, your sample data set is too short, and it is not text, it seems to be an image.

Comment: Also,  take a look at this and see if it helps you get started.  It shows how to do fft of data from a csv file, and from generated numpy arrays.  If you want something specific to your data, please post as per my previous note.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52690632/analyzing-seasonality-of-google-trend-time-series-using-fft/52691914